# How to hide blank/black activity window behind the Dialog

Tags: android

I have one Activity which displayed some Dialog boxes and Progress bars.
This activity does not have call to setContentView as this Activity does not have Screen Layout. It has been just used for displaying Dialogs and progress bar dialogs.

Now what happens is that Activity Displays Dialog box along with the Blank Activity Window on back of the Dialog, So i want to hide make it transparent so it will look like we are just displaying Dialog.

Thank,
PP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this attribute for your activity

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
```

This will make activity background transparent.
In your activity tag(in manifest) which is displaying progressbar or dialog
put this above attribute `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent`
This will work...

Answer (score 0):

Try applying the dialog theme to this activity:

In your manifest file add to the `activity` element this attribute: `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"`

Answer (score 0):

Copied from [background - Android: make everything around dialog darker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518882/android-make-everything-around-dialog-darker-than-default)

> All you need to do is play around with the dimAmount field in the
>
> ```
> WindowManager.LayoutParams:
>
> WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = myDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
> lp.dimAmount = 0.7f
> ```