# Android: make everything around Dialog darker than default

Tags: android, background, dialog, transparent

i have a custom dialog with following style:

```
<style name="webtogo_app_style"  parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

It shows a borderless dialog, and anything behind gets (slightly) darker. My designer wants that everything behind got ever more dark than Android's default, but not completely black.

Is there a setting for this at all?

The only workaround I can think of is to use a full-screen activity instead of a dialog and just fill up the whole screen with semitransparent color (e.g. #99000000) and then draw my dialog over it. Is there an easier way?

Thanks!

Comment: Your way sounds pretty easy. I think overriding dialog and creating a custom one would take more effort

Answer (score 38, accepted):

All you need to do is play around with the `dimAmount` field in the `WindowManager.LayoutParams`:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = myDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.dimAmount = 0.7f
```

Answer (score 27):

If you are creating custom dialog with theme translucent, you have to add below line as well.
and you can control dim amount using above answer's code.

```
myDialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```

For me it looks like below:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = myDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.dimAmount = 0.7f
myDialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```

Comment: I would like to add that myDialog.show() must be first called.

Comment: For me it only worked after adding: `window.setAttributes(lp);`
(That method fires an event.)

Answer (score 1):

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp=getWindow().getAttributes();
//set transparency of background
lp.dimAmount=0.6f;  // dimAmount between 0.0f and 1.0f, 1.0f is completely dark
//lp.width = 200; 
//lp.height =  300; 
myDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
myDialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing this

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

where dialog is the name of the dialogue box created.