# How to hide the main activity when showing a dialog activity

Tags: android

My appliation do the following:

1. Start a alarm
2. after 10 second
3. open a Activity (ThemeDialog)

The output is as follows
[image]

I would like to do the following:

Just show the dialog without showing the main activity

But the current situation is that the main activity is opened when I open my dialog activity.

How to hide it (when the alarm timesup, i just want to display a dialog)? Just like the following screen shot:
http://www.whatsappen.nl/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/popup21.jpg

[image]

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583579/how-to-hide-blank-black-activity-window-behind-the-dialog

Comment: I have checked out the above answer, it teaches you how to make the background of the activity to be transparent~ but my case which using the android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog, could also has transparent background. so still has a problem on hiding the Main Activity : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just also finish activity and than open new activity. New Activity' s style to `android:theme="@style/Theme.Translucent"` in your manifest file. And than set a view maybe empty textview, open dialog.

Comment: my new activity style to
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog

so that it show as dialog now, should I add one more attribute? how to hide my original activity

Comment: android:theme="@style/Theme.Translucent" style attribute make hide activity's background. You will change MainActivity style only shown StartAlarm button and helloworld text thus create new activity and it have @style/Theme.Translucent attr. Your struct is MainActivity open Translucent activity and finish, translucent activity open dialog activity.

Comment: thanks. About MainActivity open Translucent activity and finish, when the alarm times up, when it open Translucent activity, then how to finish the MainActivity? I am a super beginer. Could you give me some code for finishing the Main Activity? (for example, how to do it in the onCreate of my Translucent activity? or there are other methods?)

Comment: Could you send your code in my mail and I will fix and send you. nurisezgin.sezgin@gmail.com

Comment: Thank you for helping me to fix the problem~ I saw you added a line "sendBroadcast(new Intent(MainActivity.finishIntent));" to close my MainActivity App, it works!

I guess your suggested solution above may also be another approach to do the same staff, I mark it as correct, if in the future some people try on this stuff, then they will have 2 methods for reference.

Answer (score 0):

you can acheive this by using [custom dialog](http://shaikhhamadali.blogspot.com/2013/09/types-of-dialogbox-part-two-custom.html)
.in this give background color to black it will hide back activity

or you can acheive this by launching activity as dialog

Start activity as dialog i used this

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

now when i startActivity(in) it displays like dialog.

Comment: my task is like this screenshot:
http://www.whatsappen.nl/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/popup21.jpg

i guess I can not set background to black

Comment: My MainActivity2 already using the <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
so now is a dialog, but I want to hide the MainActivity :) I am a super beginner, how to hide the MainActivity?

Comment: what is your task,why you want to do this,may be there could be an other approach for your problem @RicoChan

Answer (score -1):

instead of showing dialog in activity you can directly use dialog theme in manifest file for activity.and use that activity as a dialog box.